# ¿cómo hacer para que se reconozca los atributos del modulo cv2?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, cv2

estoy trabajando con el modulo cv2 en python, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 import cv2
 import pylab as plt
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

 from utils.matchSift import matchSIFTdescr
 from utils.loadDatacsv import load
 sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(contrastThreshold=0.04)

 import numpy as np
```

cuando ejecuto el codigo me genera el siguiente error:
**AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'**
los mismo pasa cuando intento llamar el atributo xfeatures3d. intenté importarlos con from cada atributo y tampoco funciona. ya verifiqué que el modulo cv2 esté correctamente instalado.

Comment: Has verificado si tiene esos atributos?

Comment: A mi me da el error `/io/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp:1207: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'create'` que tiene pinta de ser difícil de arreglar...